# Closing an app from my app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have developed an app which **password protects** another app ( say app A). So when I try to open app A, an activity pops *on top* of A prompting the user to enter password. Upon incorrect entry, it should close that activity and **also close app A**, which is **directly under it**.

Now I tried to do this using this code:

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = Unlock.am.getRunningAppProcesses();
                   for(int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++)
                   {
                       ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
                       if(info.processName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.A")){
                          pid = info.pid;
                          break;
                       } 
                   }
                android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

But it does not work.

Later I realized that this is probably because the process of app A is not a direct **child** of my app's process ( that is, my app did not call app A). So is there anyway I can close but *not necessarily* kill app A from my app? What I mean to say is, killing app A is *optional* but closing it is **mandatory**.

Comment: I'm not well versed in android, but is it not possible to get a reference to the other app's activity and then `finish()` it?

Comment: In this case, for me to get a reference to that activity, I'd have to launch it from my app, which is not something I want ( as of now). So this is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to kill another app process. but you can take the user to home screen upon entering wrong password...

```
private void launchHomeScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // finish our Activity (based on your requirement)
}
```

Comment: An acceptable work-around. Now I will have to restructure my code around it. :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService("activity");
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.A");
```

You'll need to add the following permission to your manifest.

```
 <uses-permission> android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" </uses-permission>
```